# AWS Target group - Failing health check - Target Path not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I'm running a java application on ECS and the task is failing due to failed target healthcheck. I suppose this is happening due to the target path.
This application does not have a frontend and its main work is - if anyone hits the url, it frowards the traffic to a different url. I have tried keeping it '/' or a path which does not have a frontend.

Can the target healthcheck be skipped anyhow? 
Is there any wildcard I can use in place of PATH to accept any path?
Or any way this issue can be dealt?

Comment: You can provide the HTTP code expected by the healthcheck. If you application redirect to another route, you can set the HTTP code 302.

Comment: Looks like moving http code to 302 is working.. Thanks a lot!